# Grails Plugin Uploadr doesn't run

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use uploadr but I cannot put it to work... Even the [Uploadr-demo](https://github.com/4np/grails-uploadr-demo) does not run.

So, it's what I have tried so far:

Using Grails 2.4.2 and adding the plugin in a existing project:
I get this error when I run the project:

```
| Error 2014-07-16 16:00:54,667 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/jquery.tipTip.minified.js
| Error 2014-07-16 16:00:54,697 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/tipTip.css
| Error 2014-07-16 16:00:54,727 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/jquery.uploadr.js
| Error 2014-07-16 16:00:54,754 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/jquery.uploadr.css
```

However the server starts, but when I try to open the page using uploadr I get this error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
[...]
Class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Module [tipTip] depends on resource [/assets/jquery.tipTip.minified.js] but the file cannot be found
```

The page I'm trying to open is just to call the uploadr demo:

```
 <head>
    <g:javascript library='jquery' />
    <r:require modules="uploadr"/>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</head>
<body>
    <uploadr:demo/>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</body>
```

The BuildConfig:

```
    plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"

    //uploadr
    runtime ":resources:latest.integration"
    compile ":modernizr:latest.integration"
    compile ":uploadr:latest.integration"
    compile ":quartz:latest.integration" //1.0.1"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

As it didn't work I tried to download the [Uploadr-demo](https://github.com/4np/grails-uploadr-demo) from github.
First it I couldn't import (I'm using Spring Tool Suite v.:3.5.1.RELEASE) because the demo is to grails 2.3.3. Fine, I got grails 2.3.3, and again it didn't work. This time a new error:

```
Loading Grails 2.3.3
|Environment set to development
........
|Compiling 10 source files
..
|Compiling 154 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr-demo/target/work/plugins/uploadr-0.8.2/grails-app/controllers/hungry/wombat/UploadController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'hungry.wombat.UploadController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
/home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr-demo/target/work/plugins/uploadr-0.8.2/grails-app/controllers/hungry/wombat/UploadController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'hungry.wombat.UploadController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
/home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr-demo/target/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration/DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
 /home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr-demo/target/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration/DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
 4 errors
```

I also tried to create a new project with grails 2.3.3, but it doesn't even compile:

```
Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for partial output)
Command: GrailsCommand(P/grails-uploadr> compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies)
---- System.out ----
Loading Grails 2.3.3
.
|Environment set to development
..........
|Compiling 79 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
/home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr/target/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration/DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
/home/ainsoph/workspace-sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/grails-uploadr/target/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration/DbdocController.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
2 errors
```

When I tried to create a new project with grails 2.3.3 I first changed the $GRAILS_HOME to point to 2.3.3 and I called spring from a terminal that had its path updated

Well I tried everything that I could think or find on Google... Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose JDK 8 is used which is only supported from Grails 2.4 and above. So your second attempt to use Grails 2.3.3 will not work until you fall back to JDK 7.

Comment: @dmahapatro, Indeed I was using JDK 8. I tried to fall back to JDK 7(Oracle jdk1.7.0_65), but still the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a work around, it's running, but still with errors...
I installed Grails 2.3.3 and Oracle jdk1.7.0_65. Using both I can create a new project where uploadr works, and I also can run the uploadr-demo, but both with the errors below:

```
Groovy: compiler mismatch Project level is: 2.1 Workspace level is 2.3
Groovy compiler level expected by the project does not match workspace compiler level. 
Go to Project properties -> Groovy compiler to set the Groovy compiler level for this project   uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7        uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7    Groovy compiler mismatch problem


The resource is a duplicate of .link_to_grails_plugins/hibernate-3.6.10.4/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties and was not copied to the output folder   messages.properties /uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7/.link_to_grails_plugins/resources-1.2.1/grails-app/i18n   Unknown Java Problem
Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'br.eti.andersonq.UploadrController'.    UploadrController.groovy    /uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7/grails-app/controllers/br/eti/andersonq   line 1  Java Problem
Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'br.eti.andersonq.UploadrController'.    UploadrController.groovy    /uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7/grails-app/controllers/br/eti/andersonq   line 1  Java Problem
The resource is a duplicate of .link_to_grails_plugins/resources-1.2.9-SNAPSHOT/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties and was not copied to the output folder messages.properties /Blogito/.link_to_grails_plugins/uploadr-0.8.2/grails-app/i18n  Unknown Java Problem
Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.   DbdocController.groovy  /uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7/.link_to_grails_plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration   line 1  Java Problem
Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'grails.plugin.databasemigration.DbdocController'.   DbdocController.groovy  /uploadr-Grails2.3.3-JDK7/.link_to_grails_plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/databasemigration   line 1  Java Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out a solution to everything \o/

uploadr doesn't seem to work with any grails version newer then 2.3.3

The errors 'Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature' are due a incompatibility between grails 2.3.3 and JDK8. However to solve properly it is necessary to also change the STS.ini from spring to use JDK7. Because even though I had changed all my system and preferences inside spring to use JDK7 it wasn't enough.

STS.ini is located at:

```
springsource/sts-3.5.1.RELEASE/STS.ini
```

and add/change:

```
-vm
/path/to/your/jdk/installation
```

to me it was:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java
```